# rails Object.blank? and whitespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The rails documentation describes `Object.blank?` as such:

An object is blank if it’s false, empty, or a whitespace string. For example, "", " ", nil, [], and {} are blank.

```
def blank?
  respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
end
```

(from: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank%3F)

What I don't understand is how it's achieving the functionality of treating whitespace strings as blank.

`" ".empty?` returns false. Can anyone shed some light on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's overridden for Strings:

From activesupport/core_ext/blank.rb

```
class String #:nodoc:
  def blank?
    self !~ /\S/
  end
end
```

Comment: great, thank you. i was trying to find it here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/, but it's not there. is there another api doc webpage which would have revealed this?

Comment: I went right to the source. There are several class overrides for `blank?`.